# sonarqube plugin/matrix for level of inheritance for PHP

Tags: php, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-4.5

How to show level of inheritance for PHP language in SonarQube?

suggest any plugin or matrix for PHP language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SonarQube PHP plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/PHP+Plugin) does not have such a rule for the moment. There's an [open ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPHP-371) for that.